# PostgreSQL distinct rows joined with a count of distinct values in one column

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, distinct, aggregate-functions

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.4, and I have a table with 13 million rows and with data roughly as follows:

```
  a  | b | u  | t 
-----+---+----+----
 foo | 1 |  1 | 10
 foo | 1 |  2 | 11
 foo | 1 |  2 | 11
 foo | 2 |  4 | 1
 foo | 3 |  5 | 2
 bar | 1 |  6 | 2
 bar | 2 |  7 | 2
 bar | 2 |  8 | 3
 bar | 3 |  9 | 4
 bar | 4 | 10 | 5
 bar | 5 | 11 | 6
 baz | 1 | 12 | 1
 baz | 1 | 13 | 2
 baz | 1 | 13 | 2
 baz | 1 | 13 | 3
```

There are indices on `md5(a)`, on `b`, and on `(md5(a), b)`. (In reality, `a` may contain values longer than 4k chars.) There is also a primary key column of type `SERIAL` which I have omitted above.

I'm trying to build a query which will return the following results:

```
  a  | b | u  | t  | z 
-----+---+----+----+---
 foo | 1 |  1 | 10 | 3
 foo | 1 |  2 | 11 | 3
 foo | 2 |  4 | 1  | 3
 foo | 3 |  5 | 2  | 3
 bar | 1 |  6 | 2  | 5
 bar | 2 |  7 | 2  | 5
 bar | 2 |  8 | 3  | 5
 bar | 3 |  9 | 4  | 5
 bar | 4 | 10 | 5  | 5
 bar | 5 | 11 | 6  | 5
```

In these results, all rows are deduplicated as if `GROUP BY a, b, u, t` were applied, `z` is a count of distinct values of `b` for every partition over `a`, and only rows with a `z` value greater than 2 are included.

I can get just the `z` filter working as follows:

```
SELECT a, COUNT(b) AS z from (SELECT DISTINCT a, b FROM t) AS foo GROUP BY a
  HAVING COUNT(b) > 2;
```

However, I'm stumped on combining this with the rest of the data in the table.

What's the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first step can be simpler already:

```sql
SELECT md5(a) AS md5_a, count(DISTINCT b) AS z
FROM   t
GROUP  BY 1
HAVING count(DISTINCT b) > 2;
```

Working with `md5(a)` in place of `a`, since `a` can obviously be *very* long, and you already have an index on `md5(a)` etc.

Since your table is *big*, you need an efficient query. This should be among the fastest possible solutions - with adequate index support. Your index on `(md5(a), b)` is instrumental but - assuming `b`, `u`, and `t` are small columns - an index on `(md5(a), b, u, t)` would be even better for the second step of the query (the lateral join).

Your desired end result:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (md5(t.a), b, u, t)
       t.a, t.b, t.u, t.t, a.z
FROM  (
   SELECT md5(a) AS md5_a, count(DISTINCT b) AS z
   FROM   t
   GROUP  BY 1
   HAVING count(DISTINCT b) > 2
   ) a
JOIN   t ON md5(t.a) = md5_a
ORDER  BY 1, 2, 3, 4;  -- optional
```

Or probably faster, yet:

```sql
SELECT a, b, u, t, z
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (1, 2, 3, 4)
          md5(t.a) AS md5_a, t.b, t.u, t.t, t.a
   FROM   t
   ) t
JOIN  (
   SELECT md5(a) AS md5_a, count(DISTINCT b) AS z
   FROM   t
   GROUP  BY 1
   HAVING count(DISTINCT b) > 2
   ) z USING (md5_a)
ORDER  BY 1, 2, 3, 4;  -- optional
```

Detailed explanation for `DISTINCT ON`:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Comment: Does `DISTINCT ON ()` have any performance benefit over `Lateral Join`, or vice versa?

Comment: @AbhishekDalvi: Two very different tools. (I removed the parts of my answer now that were voided by question clarification.) Detailed assessment of `DISTINCT ON` performance in the linked answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/939860. Details for `LATERAL`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28557803/939860